# Why does the Product version change when I publish a web application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a web application for which I specify AssemblyVersion in AsemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

This gives me a incrementing Product version for each build (what I want).

But as soon as I publish the application, the Product version reverts to some fixed value, presumably in the build that is done automatically right before publish.

Why does this happen? And is there a way to have incrementing Product versions with publish?

Comment: Look into build process. Build processes normally constructed to override default version values in the assemblyInfo.